# Python to VB6 conversion

Tags: python, vb6

I have a question about the code below:

```
def getJenksBreaks( dataList, numClass ):

dataList.sort()

mat1 = []
for i in range(0,len(dataList)+1):
    temp = []
    for j in range(0,numClass+1):
        temp.append(0)
    mat1.append(temp)
```

`mat1` will for example look like this

```
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0

0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0

0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0

0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

Afterwards, `mat2` is created:

```
mat2 = []
for i in range(0,len(dataList)+1):
    temp = []
    for j in range(0,numClass+1):
        temp.append(0)
mat2.append(temp)
```

and then `mat1` and `mat2` are modified:

```
for i in range(1,numClass+1):
    mat1[1][i] = 1
    mat2[1][i] = 0
    for j in range(2,len(dataList)+1):
        mat2[j][i] = float('inf')
```

When I see this line:

```
 mat1[1][i] = 1
```

it seems to me that the item at an XY position is changed.

I would like to port this code to VB6, and I don't see any way to reflect such a behavior in VB6. A collection would not be able to do that, I mean to access items using X and Y, would it?

Comment: Why would you convert *into* a language that's been deprecated for years?

Comment: I need to integrate this into a huge VB6 application that I can not easily convert to a different language. It is currently easier for me to convert this Python code to VB6, than convert my huge app to .NET or Python. But thanks for asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I created my own class to handle this. If somebody has a better idea, please tell me.

```
Option Explicit

Private m_XCount&
Private m_YCount&
Private m() As Variant

Public Sub Add(ByRef u() As Variant)

    If UBound(u) > m_XCount Then
        m_XCount = UBound(u)
    End If

    m_YCount = m_YCount + 1

    ReDim Preserve m(0 To m_XCount, 0 To m_YCount)

    Dim l&
    For l = 0 To UBound(u)
        m(m_XCount + l, m_YCount) = u(l + 1)
    Next l

    m_YCount = m_YCount + 1

End Sub

Private Sub Class_Initialize()

    ReDim m(0, 0)

End Sub
Public Property Get Value(ByVal uX As Long, ByVal uY As Long) As Variant

    Value = m(uX, uY)

End Property
Public Property Let Value(ByVal uX As Long, ByVal uY As Long, ByVal uValue)

    m(uX, uY) = uValue

End Property
```